# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table <Entity> when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've read every article that stack overflow recommended to me and have not yet solved my problem. This is my first post and I apologize if it is an easy fix, but no matter what I save first (AfterCooler, F1046, or BasicInfo, I get the exception for explicitly inserting AfterCooler's identity. BasicInfo saves fine on it's own, but when adding F1046, saving it, or adding AfterCooler and saving it, I get this exception. AfterCooler and F1046 should have a 1 to 1, and F1046 and BasicInfo should have a one to many relationship.

Entities:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(F1046MetaDataSource))]
public partial class F1046
{
    public int F1046Id { get; set; }      
    public virtual AfterCooler AfterCooler { get; set; }

    public int BasicInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual BasicInfo BasicInfo { get; set; }
}

class F1046MetaDataSource
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int F1046Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BasicInfo")]
    public int BasicInfoId { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(AfterCoolerMetaDataSource))]
public partial class AfterCooler : IComparer<AfterCooler>
{

    public string AfCoolReasonChange { get; set; }
    public string VendorAF { get; set; }

    public int F1046Id { get; set; }
    public virtual F1046 F1046 { get; set; }  
}

class AfterCoolerMetaDataSource
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("F1046")]
    public int F1046Id { get; set; }
}


[MetadataType(typeof(BasicInfoMetaDataSource))]
public partial class BasicInfo
{
    public int BasicInfoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateBasicInfo { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<F1046> F1046 { get; set; }

    public BasicInfo()
    {
        F1046 = new List<F1046>();
    }

}

class BasicInfoMetaDataSource
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BasicInfoId { get; set; }
}
```

Repository methods:

```
public void SaveAfterCooler(AfterCooler afterCooler)
    {
        if (afterCooler.F1046Id == 0)
        {
            context.AfterCooler_.Add(afterCooler);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(afterCooler).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

(this looks the same for essentially every entity, just swapping the contexts/id's..)

I have a view which has elements of the BasicInfo (but not the id's) and of the F1046 (but not the id's), the members of the F1046 (AfterCooler, its properties, etc..) like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("After Cooler Reason")
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.F1046.AfterCooler.AfCoolReasonChange, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.F1046.AfterCooler.AfCoolReasonChange, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
```

and it gets submitted to a controller method which I shortened to something like this..

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult CreateF1046(F1046_CreateViewModel fm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            BasicInfo bi = fm.BasicInfo;
            F1046 f1 = fm.F1046;
            _f1046Repository.SaveF10461(f1);
            bi.F1046.Add(f1);

            return RedirectToAction("Summary", bi);

        }
```

I've tried everything in every order or at least it feels that way.. I'm sorry if this doesn't make much sense, the program takes a lot of fields in and I tried to leave out the irrelevant ones. The ViewModel mentioned above for the controller method contains a BasicInfo object and an F1046 object for relevance.
 Thank you.

Comment: "F1046"... I don't even want to continue reading. Seriously, though, look at the object right before the call to .Add and ensure the **Object**'s Id is null/negative

Comment: I apologize for the naming conventions, but the pk/fk for AfterCooler is 0, but what steps should I take to make it what it needs to be? (null or it's parent id)?